# How do you implement type-specific functionality when using polymorphism does NOT make sense?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, inheritance, if-statement, polymorphism

A common red flag that an OOP language is not being leveraged properly looks like this:

```
if (typeof(x) == T1)
{
    DoSomethingWithT1(x);
}
else if (typeof(x) == T2)
{
    DoSomethingWithT2(x);
}
```

The standard "fix" for such design issues is to make `T1` and `T2` both share an interface, either through inheritance of a base type or implementation of a common interface (in languages that support it); for example, in C# a solution might be:

```
public interface IT
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

However, sometimes you want to implement functionality that differs based on the type of an object but that functionality does *not* belong within that object's type; thus polymorphism seems the wrong way to go.

For example, consider the case of a UI that provides a view of a given clump of data. Supposing this view is capable of rendering various layouts and controls depending on the type of data being presented, how would you implement this type-specific rendering without a bunch of `if`/`else` statements?

For reasons that I *hope* are obvious, putting the rendering logic in the type itself strikes me as a very bad decision in this case. On the other hand, without coupling the type of data object to its visual presentation I have a hard time seeing how the `if`/`else` scenario is avoided.

Here's a concrete example: I work on a trading application which utilizes many different pricing models for various market products. These different models are represented by types inheriting from a common `PricingModel` base; and each type is associated with a completely different set of parameters. When the user wants to view the parameters for a particular pricing model (for a particular product), currently these are displayed by a form which detects the type of the model and displays an appropriate set of controls. My question is how this could be implemented more elegantly than it is currently (with a big `if`/`else` block).

I realize this probably seems like a very basic question; it's just one of those gaps in my knowledge (of solid OOP principles? design patterns? common sense?) that I figured it's about time to fix.

Answer (score 1):

We are injecting (Spring.Net) such functionality into dictionaries by type.

```
IDictionary<Type, IBlahImplementor> blahImplementors;

blahImplementors[thingy.GetType()].Do(thingy);
```

This dictionary could be managed by a kind of repository which provides the functionality.

As an implementation detail, the implementor usually knows the type it depends on an can provide it itself:

```
interface IBlahImplementor
{
  Type ForType { get; }

  void Do(object thingy);
}
```

Then it is added to the dictionary like this:

```
IEnumerably<IBlahImplementor> blahImplementors;
foreach (var implementor in blahImplementors)
{
  blahImplementors.Add(implementor.ForType, implementor);
}
```

---

Remark: IMHO, it is very important to understand that some things do NOT belong into a class, even if providing subtype-specific implementations would make life much easier.

---

**Edit**: Finally understood your concrete example.

It is actually about instancing the right UI control to show the pricing models parameters. It should be possible with the pattern I described above. If you don't have a single UI control for a pricing model, you either create it or you write a UI configurer or something like this which sets up the required controls.

```
interface IPricingModelUiConfigurer
{
  Type PricingModelType { get; }
  void SetupUi(Control parent, IPricingModel model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you described is pretty much exactly the use case for the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

**EDIT**: For your concrete example, you could apply the visitor pattern like this:

```
// interface used to add external functionality to pricing models
public interface PricingModelVisitor {
    void visitPricingModel1(PricingModel1 m);
    void visitPricingModel2(PricingModel2 m);
    ...
}
// your existing base-class, with added abstract accept() method to accept a visitor
public abstract class PricingModelBase {
    public abstract void accept(PricingModelVisitor v);
    ...
}
// concrete implementations of the PricingModelBase implement accept() by calling the 
// appropriate method on the visitor, passing themselves as the argument
public class PricingModel1 : PricingModelBase { 
    public void accept(PricingModelVisitor v) { v.visitPricingModel1(this); }
    ...
}
public class PricingModel2 : PricingModel {
    public void accept(PricingModelVisitor v) { v.visitPricingModel2(this); }
    ...
}
// concrete implementation of the visitor interface, in this case with the new 
// functionality of adding the appropriate controls to a parent control
public class ParameterGuiVisitor : PricingModelVisitor {
    private Control _parent;
    public ParameterGuiVisitor(Control parent) { _parent = parent; }
    visitPricingModel1(PricingModel1 m) {
        // add controls to _parent for PricingModel1
    }
    visitPricingModel2(PricingModel2 m) {
        // add controls to _parent for PricingModel1
    }
}
```

now, instead of using a big `if`-`else` block when you need to display the edit-controls for the parameters of a specific subtype of `PricingModelVisitor`, you can simply call

```
somePricingModel.accept(new ParameterGuiVisitor(parentControl))
```

and it will populate the appropriate GUI for you.

Comment: Visitor is probably not flexible enough. You can't add visited types dynamically. You only can dynamically add implementations of visitors.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding visited types dynamically"? The visitor pattern easily allows you to add new types by simply adding a new method to the visitor interface that deals with this new type. This will then at compile-time force you to update all existing visitor implementations to appropriately handle this new type, something that might be easily overlooked with a dictionary-based solution.

Comment: Sometimes it needs injecting, easy registering of types, adding types at runtime, adding types which are not known by the assembly which specifies the visitor interface etc. I don't say that dynamic is better then static, I just say that it is *probably not flexible enough* for the problem described here.

Comment: "Sometimes it needs ..." - none of which was mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use common interface approach as you describe and  Command pattern to trigger methods with "functionality does not belong within that object's type". I think this won't break solid OOP principles.